# Can libraries be forced to receive ETH as the recipient of another contract's selfdestruct() or as the miner reward?

Tags: solidity, library

At the end of the [Libraries](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/contracts.html#libraries) section in the Solidity docs, it says that libraries cannot receiver Ether:

> In comparison to contracts, libraries are restricted in the following
> ways:
>
> - they cannot have state variables
> - they cannot inherit nor be inherited
> - **they cannot receive Ether**
> - they cannot be destroyed

The main avenue for sending/receiving ETH (marking user functions or the fallback function as `payable`) is prevented in libraries by the compiler--library code with `payable` won't even compile. But what about ETH sent to a library as a result of another contract calling selfdestruct()? Or if the library's address is designated as the coinbase address for miner rewards? In normal contracts (not libraries), there is no way to block the receipt of ETH when it is sent to the contract by these last two methods.

Do Ethereum clients have code that specifically disallows the receipt of ETH by a library in these two special cases? If so, is it a "general purpose" block that somehow prevents the receipt of ETH by a library under *any* circumstances, or is it specifically a block on these two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, answering your questions, yes! Libraries are able to forcibly receive ether if we use them in the `selfdestruct` or as the recipient miner.

Also, this is a good way to lose funds for ever. There is no way to get them back.

I tried the following code and deployed it on Rinkeby. The library got the ethers, but when calling the `send` function to try to withdraw the balance, it fails every time.

We can see the library balance in https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x96d41a99ddd9892eCfB8a923B083332EA7c83eCf

The `SelfDestruct` contract is deployed at: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa55Bb46B5929269Db38fDF4E74e8FE032c4F5b29

Check the transactions and you will see how I sent `0.001` ether to the contract and then `selfdestruct` it, forcing it to send it's balance to the library.

Now the library has the balance but the `send` function does not work. The `balance` function in the library works and it shows it's own balance.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

library LibraryToForciblySendFundsTo {
    function balance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function send(address payable recipient) public {
        recipient.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}

contract SelfDestruct { 

    uint256 public time;

    function updateTime() public {
        time = block.timestamp;
    }

    receive() external payable {}

    function destroy(address payable libraryAddress) public {
        selfdestruct(libraryAddress);
    }

    function balance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

 }
```

Comment: I just read that if a library function is not marked `pure` or `view`, it won't be compiled into the library's ABI (and thus not be callable). Is it possible that the send() call isn't working because of this?

Comment: Yes, it should be that. Because from Remix I'm not able to see the `send` function, only the `balance` function. So, to "force" a call to the `send` function after the library was deployed, I had to change the keyword `library` to `contract` to load the contract in Remix as a regular contract and then I called the `send` function and it reverted.

Comment: After changing `library` to `contract`, is it possible to confirm that the bytecode for the `send()` function is actually present there at the deployed address (versus not there at all)?

Comment: I just used the "decompile bytecode" feature on Etherscan and it does look like the bytecode for the `send()` function is there. Interesting results!